# R - conditional cumsum using multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm new to stackoverflow So I hope I post my question in the right format. I have a test dataset with three columns where rank is the ranking of a cell, Esvalue is the value of a cell and zoneID is an area identifier(Note! in the real dataset I have up to 40.000 zoneIDs)

```
    rank<-seq(0.1,1,0.1)
    Esvalue<-seq(10,1)
    zoneID<-rep(seq.int(1,2),times=5)

    rank Esvalue zoneID
    0.1      10      1
    0.2       9      2
    0.3       8      1
    0.4       7      2
    0.5       6      1
    0.6       5      2
    0.7       4      1
    0.8       3      2
    0.9       2      1
    1.0       1      2
```

I want to calculate the following:
% ES value <- For each rank, including all lower ranks, the cumulative % share of the total ES value relative to the ES value of all zones

```
    cumsum(df$Esvalue)/sum(df$Esvalue)
```

% ES value zone <- For each rank, including all lower ranks, the cumulative % share of the total Esvalue relative to the ESvalue of a zoneID for each zone. I tried this now using mutate and using dplyr. Both so far only give me the cumulative sum, not the share. In the end this will generate a variable for each zoneID

```
      df %>% 
    mutate(cA=cumsum(ifelse(!is.na(zoneID) & zoneID==1,Esvalue,0))) %>% 
    mutate(cB=cumsum(ifelse(!is.na(zoneID) & zoneID==2,Esvalue,0)))
```

These two variables I want to combine by 
1) calculating the abs difference between the two for all the zoneIDs
2) for each rank calculate the mean of the absolute difference over all zoneIDs

In the end the final output should look like:

```
   rank Esvalue zoneID mean_abs_diff
   0.1      10      1    0.16666667
   0.2       9      2    0.01333333
   0.3       8      1    0.12000000
   0.4       7      2    0.02000000
   0.5       6      1    0.08000000
   0.6       5      2    0.02000000
   0.7       4      1    0.04666667
   0.8       3      2    0.01333333
   0.9       2      1    0.02000000
   1.0       1      2    0.00000000
```

Now I created the last using some intermediate steps in Excel but my final dataset will be way too big to be handled by Excel. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. You also haven't loaded `dplyr`, neither you created `df`. Also, if you want to operate by `zoneID` use `group_by(zoneID) %>%` and the `mutate`. You can also create several variables in the same `mutate` call. Though, nothing I've tried helped me reproduce your desired output.

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your comments. I actually decided to calculate a different metric so I will close down this topic. Your comments did help though in getting some of the intermediate steps figured out